# Call to undefined method SerialModel::GetSerailModel() in C:\..\serialController.php on line 14

Tags: php, methods, undefined

So I'm a little new to PHP and programming and general.  I've tried in the past but always hit a brick wall.  Now that brick wall has come down and I seem to be programming a bit more then normal.  I'm currently practicing php, and am running into this issue (via WAMP server in a VM):

[Call to undefined method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UywKJ.png)

It says the issue is in my serialController.php file:

require ("Model/SerialModel.php");

//Contains non-database related function for the Coffee page

class SerialController {

function CreateSerialDropdownList() {

```
    $serialModel = new SerialModel();

    $result = "<form action = '' method = 'post' width = '200px'>

                Please select a type: 

                <select name = 'name' >

                    <option value = '%' >All</option>

                    " . $this->CreateOptionValues($serialModel->GetSerialName()) .

            "</select>

                 <input type = 'submit' value = 'Search' />

                </form>";

    return $result;

}
```

By my understanding, the logic should be that it passes the information from the file SerialModel.php into a new GetSerialName() object.  But it doesn't seem to be working.

Any assistance is appreciated.  I know have a long way to go before this is like the back of my hand, that's for sure.

Comment: Post your `Model/SerialModel.php`. It sounds like the function doesn't exist, and it may not be using magic methods (which usually start with a lowercase get, I think).

Comment: It won't let me past all the code as a reply.  Let me know if Pastebin works for you.

http://pastebin.com/aHb8HMGs

Comment: Also should provide the code for the `CreateOptionValues` function as well as the contents of `SerialNumbers.php`. My guess is that there is a line in that file that is trying to call the `GetSerialModel` method, which based on the code you pasted for `SerialModel.php`, does not exist.

Comment: You can edit your post and add the code in.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is named `GetSerialNames` (note the s)

```
function GetSerialNames() {
```

But you're calling `GetSerialName`

```
 $this->CreateOptionValues($serialModel->GetSerialName())
```

Comment: Awesome.  That cleared up the error message.  Thanks for the info.